# Comparing two strings and creating a list containing the letter and the count of that letter in the string

Tags: python, string, list, compare

I am trying to create a function that takes as input 2 strings (myString and charString) and seeing how many times the letters in charString are in myString. Then appending those values into the list. For example (“all is quiet on the western front”, “tqe”) should return [“t=4”, “q=1”, “e=4”]. Here is what I have:

```
def myProblem(myString, charString):
    myString = str(myString)
    charString = str(charString)
    count = 0
    newList = []
    for letter in charString:
        if letter in myString:
            count += 1
            newList.append(str(letter)+"="+str(count))
        else:
            pass
    return newList
```

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use [`str.count`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_count.htm), also you're not appending the list the right way. Since you want the total number, appending it on every iteration is counterproductive.

Here is a correct version:

```
def myProblem(myString, charString):
    myString = str(myString)
    charString = str(charString)
    newList = []
    for letter in charString:
        newList.append(letter +"="+str(myString.count(letter)))
    return newList

print(myProblem('all is quiet on the western front', 'tqe'))
```

**Output**

```
['t=4', 'q=1', 'e=4']
```

Note that this could be done in one line if casting both parameters is not important for you:

```
def myProblem(myString, charString):
    return [letter +"="+str(myString.count(letter)) for letter in charString ]
```

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
from collections import Counter
def myProblem(myString, charString):
    myString = str(myString)
    charString = str(charString)
    newList = []
    for letter in myString:
        if letter in charString:
            newList.append(str(letter))
        else:
            pass
    newList = dict(Counter(list(newList)))
    return newList

a = input("enter the phrase: ")
b = input("enter the letters to look for: ")

print(myProblem(a, b))
```

it just splits your input a into a list keeping only the letters that were in b and then using a counter to count how often they occurred

with a = all is quiet on the western front
and b = qte

output is: {'q': 1, 'e': 4, 't': 4}

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Xander25, you can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
input_string = "all is quiet on the western front"
char_string = "tqe"
letter_counts = Counter(input_string) # Create a counter object
# output - Counter({' ': 6, 'a': 1, 'e': 4, 'f': 1, 'h': 1, 'i': 2, 'l': 2, 'n': 3, 'o': 2, 'q': 1, 'r': 2, 's': 2, 't': 4, 'u': 1, 'w': 1})
output_counts = {letter: letter_counts[letter] for letter in char_string} # Create dictionary containing counts of letters present in char_string
# output_counts - {'e': 4, 'q': 1, 't': 4}
output_list = [letter + "=" + str(letter_counts[letter]) for letter in char_string]
# output_list - ['t=4', 'q=1', 'e=4']
```

Also, when you use collections.Counter, it doesn't throw a `key error` for any key which is not present in the dictionary, but rather gives the value `0`.